# Using Where-Clause in a query

Tags: mysql, database

I'm having problems with a Where query.
It doesn't seem to work or its not right

```
select * from FP where FP.Paid Amount => '100'
```

I'm trying to only display the people who have paid over 100 in the DB

Any Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Ehem, that code can't be real. It would never compile.

Comment: +1 only for the epicness

Comment: Just take a look at how people are upvoting you for this.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: Why would it not compile?  It looks like it would, although it doesn't appear that it do anything related to a database.

Comment: Do you really have a column with a space in its name (`Paid Amount`) ?

Comment: @recursive It has been edited.  In it's first revision it wouldn't have compiled.

Comment: What is `=>`?  Also, there's a space in your column name.  You might want to use `[Paid Amount]` instead or it probably won't be able to parse the query.  Also, is that column really holding *character* data?  Or did you mean to say `100` instead of `'100'`?

Comment: This is why M. Fowler said `"developers should stay away from SQL and leave that to DBAs"` - or something like that, I think...

Comment: If you can you should really use Entity Framework instead.

Answer (score 4):

Did you mean to do this?

```
string myQuery = "select * from FP where FP.[Paid Amount] >= '100' ";
```

Note that `=>` and `>=` are not the same.

By the way, if [Paid Amount] is a numeric column, you'll want to drop the single quotes, like this

```
string myQuery = "select * from FP where FP.[Paid Amount] >= 100 ";
```

Comment: If the column is int and you use quotes on `100`, is it going to work the way you expect? The first query seems wrong, I am not sure though

Comment: @BrunoLM that's why I added the second one. I'm just not sure if his column is int or not.

Comment: I've changed it but it still shows everyone on the DB not the ones over 100

Comment: @user3045496 Did you try the second one too?

Comment: @user3045496: The code only sets a string variable.  It does not interact with any database.

Comment: @recursive I imagine he then executes the string as a sql query, or it wouldn't show anything at all.

Comment: @Yandros:  I'm not aware of any SQL dialect that would execute it as a legal query, so I'm not so sure.

Comment: The second one gives me a Data type mismatch and the first one still displays everyone

Comment: @user3045496 Ok, try this one: `string myQuery = "select * from FP where CAST(FP.[Paid Amount] AS UNSIGNED) >= 100 ";` (but honestly, if the field is for a number, you should at least consider changing its data type)

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the '=' and the '>'. Also, a `@` of the leading '"' will prevent the compiler from trying to translate any of the string content.

```
string myQuery = @"select * from FP where FP.Paid Amount >= '100' ";
```

Comment: There are no escape characters inside of the string, so there is no reason to use a literal string here.

Comment: Not in this one, but as a rule he'd avoid problems, true?